# Deploy playframework 2.3 using cloudbees

Tags: java, deployment, cloudbees, playframework-2.3

I try to deploy my play framework 2.3 java application using cloudbees

As mentioned [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Deploying-to-CloudBees) I start my project using Play! framework 2 click start.

After migration from play 2.2.3 to play 2.3 my projects work properly. But after adding my java codes, jenkins Builds result is OK, while accessing [deployed site](http://selfservivefood.mhmhkashi.cloudbees.net/) results following:

```
 502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.4.2
```

my build.scala file:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Play.autoImport._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "ssff"
  val appVersion = "1.0 alpha"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.5.Final",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.30", javaCore,
    javaJpa
  )

  val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava).settings(
    version := appVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies,
    javaOptions in Test ++= Seq(
      "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9998",
      "-Xms512M",
      "-Xmx1536M",
      "-Xss1M",
      "-XX:MaxPermSize=384M"
    )
  )

}
```

**UPDATE**

the server log repeat this line many times:

```
/var/genapp/apps/196554ce/.genapp/control/config: line 5: alpha: command not found
```

and the access log is:

```
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:41 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:25:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
50.19.73.164 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:26:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:27:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:27:43 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:28:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:28:31 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:30:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:30:09 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:34:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:34:50 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:35:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
85.159.208.216 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:35:40 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1788.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Did you check application logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem origin was cause of changing the appName in build file. by reverting it to helloworld it worksproperly